# How to Build Dynamic Queues using Apache Air Flow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have just started to explore Apache Airflow.

Is there any way to run a job that will look into the running DAGS and move those tasks in those DAGS to new DAG by creating them and adding those tasks in it.

For Example : DAG A has four tasks, 4th one has been waiting from 7 hours to start - Goal is to create new DAG and move that tasks automatically to new DAG.

**Scenario** : Actually we have around 40 VM, and each job time varies with its own instance. For Example : Task A will take 2 hours today but might take 12 Hours tomorrow in the same DAG. What i need is to move that task to other DAG if the waiting time of any task exceed certain time to run on other VM instantly.

The main benefi is to keep all the task waiting time minimum as possible by building dynamic DAGs

Comment: What would be the benefit of dynamically moving tasks between DAGs based on how long they've been in queue?

Comment: Actually we have around 40 VM, and each job time varies with its own instance. For Example : Task A will take 2 hours today but might take 12 Hours tomorrow in the same DAG. What i need is to move that task to other DAG if the waiting time of any task exceed certain time to run on other VM instantly.

Comment: The main benefi is to keep all the task waiting time minimum as possible by building dynamic DAGs

Comment: Hmm! I'm not sure if DAGs are the right layer to control that. TaskInstances have `queue` attributes that you can set and you can have certain VMs dedicated to reading various queues to ensure that they get priority to complete. I also believe there's some sort of priority setting you can hit. Generally you want DAGs to be slowly changing entities so I'd look more into how TaskInstances get routed.

Comment: alright, can you provide some links or example in building queues using Apache Air Flow. I moslty find DAGS examples every where.

Comment: I haven't found good documentation in the wild about queues, I've ended up implementing based on digging through the codebase itself. As far as general Airflow best practices I've found this to be a really useful doc, and hopefully it'll be helpful in understanding how to best design DAGs and then you can tie that back into using queues somehow: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVN4HXtOC-HXvv00sEkoB90mxLDnCIKc/view

Comment: Yes, thats the problem, not example for building queues, looks like have to dig into it, thanks for sharing the document - Its pretty helpful.

Comment: Yup at bare minimum what I've done is have a different VM for each queue, and when you run airflow worker do `airflow worker --queues queue1,queue2` and that worker only listens to that particular queue. Then you can set the `queue` attribute in TaskInstance. If you want to go deeper take a look at `settings.py`, you'll find that airflow imports a function called `policy` from `airflow_local_settings` and runs that during the DagBag step, which you can use to administratively enforce how tasks are routed to queues. Hopefully that gives you a few threads to pull on. Good luck!

Comment: okay thanks, i have used RabbitMQ for now, will see how apache airflow handles these scenario once some examples will be avaiable.

Comment: @ShanKhan were you able to solve this problem using airflow ?

Comment: No, i used RabbitMQ , and it does the job pretty well.